# How would fully autonomous holographic killer drone work wirelessly?

Tags: technological-development, artificial-intelligence, light, drone

Now we have drones capable of dodging missiles and sometimes evade radar detection and carry out assassination without ever exposing our soldiers to danger, given time could we fly holographic version instead over thousands of miles for espionage or other convert missions like killing enemies? Currently we can project 3D hologram in the air and using sound vibrations aimed at your skin to produce the physical feeling of touch, so how far in terms of technological advancement do we need to fly a fully autonomous holographic killer drone across vast distances?

Fully autonomous means it doesn't require a human operator to fly it, holographic means it is made of light, killer is I believe self explanatory, and wirelessly means it it untethered.

Comment: Maybe put a projector on the actual drone, so it can project a holographic drone?  The holographic drone looks a lot cooler because it does not need to be aerodynamic.  It actually looks like an armadillo who is flying by swimming.   No-one looks at the real drone with the projector because of the armadillo.   More of a glyptodont because it is huge.

Comment: What is a " fully autonomous holographic killer drone?" A physical drone that flies above the target and which uses 3D telemetry data, a physical drone that projects the hologram of an incoming missile to their targets (but not the real thing) or one that "just a holographic projection of a drone, nothing actually material in what you see in the sky"?

Answer (score 2):

> Currently we can project 3D hologram in the air and using sound vibrations aimed at your skin to produce the physical feeling of touch,

I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding here.

- An holographic projection appears like a real 3D object, but it is made only of light
- The feeling of touch is induced by pressure waves, and it requires only the pressure waves to be triggered, not the holographic image

An holographic projection, bein made of light, can only kill with it. But at this point why would one bother in engineering the interference pattern to create the hologram? Just fire the laser on the target.

Apart from that, creating an holographic image brings no added value to killing the target. A bullet doesn't need an holographic machinegun to kill its target.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding about how holograms work here, as well as in Hollywood, which has perpetuated the myth of unsupported holograms.

Holograms work by manipulating light so that to your eyes and brain, they appear to be coming from a real object.  The problem is that you can only see a hologram if you can see its source through the hologram.

Imagine a wall that is a hologram projector.  Next, imagine that the wall is projecting the hologram of a drone.  Then consider that the light is coming from the wall.  The drone may appear to be inside the wall or outside of it, but the light must still come from the wall.

So, if we have an open space with a free-standing holographic wall, as long as you are looking at the wall, you can see the hologram.  Now, let us suppose that the wall is projecting the hologram of a drone into the space in front of it.

If you were to move so that your view of the wall beyond the drone was such that parallax moved the drone off the wall, where the parts of the drone should be beyond which you don't have a direct view of the emitter wall, *you don't see the drone*.  If you were to try to walk around the holographic drone, the further the emitter wall falls into your peripheral vision, the less clear the image will seem, until you're not looking at the wall at all, and you can't see the image of the drone either.

So, a hologram emitter is a display technology.  It doesn't produce independent entities, it merely produces the *illusion* of independent entities.

Therefore, without a hologram emitter that can travel across vast distances, the holograms that it emits can't do so either.

Finally, technologies to produce the illusion of tangibility are similarly short-ranged, or even more so than holograms.